# QNetworkAccessManager->networkAccessible() always return UnknownAccessibility (-1)

Tags: qt, blackberry-10

Please consider the following snippet of Code:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* netManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);    
if(netManager->networkAccessible() == QNetworkAccessManager::UnknownAccessibility)
{
    Utilities::showToast("UnknownAccessibility", "Retry");
}
if(netManager->networkAccessible() == QNetworkAccessManager::NotAccessible)
{
    Utilities::showToast("NotAccessible", "Retry");
}
if(netManager->networkAccessible() == QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible)
{
    Utilities::showToast("Accessible", "Retry");
}
```

This permanently returns -1. Is there another way to detect Data and Wifi settings for BB Native?

Comment: I have also tried the following addition to the above mentioned code:

QNetworkConfigurationManager configManager;
 netManager->setConfiguration(configManager.defaultConfiguration());

Answer (score 1):

You might be using an old version of BB10.
I looked at the git history for qnetworkaccessmanager.h and it seems that this class was updated after 10.0. For instance the commit:

> ```
> commit 9efd40bd776e1c5e7ce9feeac63b3673250291b6 Date: Thu Feb 28 17:41:59 2013 +0100
>
> QNetworkAccessManager: track online / accessible state without session
>
> In particular, set online state right upon construction of the
> QNetworkAccessManager instance. Therefor, QNAM needs an instance of a
> QNetworkConfigurationManager internally.
> Before, this would only work properly if a network session was created.
> Now, networkAccessible() returns the correct status.
> ```

Seems to indicate that on BB10.0, the networkAccessible() would work correctly if a network session was created (and opened).